# highcharts histrogram with dates

Tags: date, highcharts, histogram

I have a multidimensional array structured like this: `[[year,month,day,value],[year2,month2,day2,value2],[year3,month3,day3,value3]...]`. Each value is an integer number. I would like to build an Highcharts Histogram chart: in the xAxis there are the YEARS, in the yAxis the MONTHS. Now, in the columns i would like to have the sum of the VALUES for that year (example: column 2009 with the sum of all values that have 2009 as year). In the markers, i would like to have them 
distributed according to the month of that year (example: in column 2009, markers with month 1 at the left, and with month 12 at the right of that column, and also for other columns).

Is it possible to do with this type of chart? Thanks a lot.

```js
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/histogram-bellcurve.js">
</script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
 var data = [[2014,1,10,3],[2014,2,3,9],[2013,12,4,7],[2012,3,6,7],[2009,8,5,9],[2010,11,31,5],[2016,1,1,3],[2011,12,13,9],[2016,2,14,7],[2017,5,29,6],[2008,8,15,4],[2013,11,31,5]];
Highcharts.setOptions({
    colors: ['green', 'blue', 'yellow', 'orange', 'red', 'violet', 'pink', 'brown', 'black']
});
$(function () {
        Highcharts.chart('prova',{
                title: {
                    text: 'Distribuzione articoli'
                },
                xAxis: [{
                    title: { text: 'Anno' },
                    min: 2009,
                    max: 2017,
                    type: 'category'
                    }, {
                    title: { text: 'Mese' },
                    opposite: true,
                }],
                yAxis: [{
                    title: { text: 'Giorno' },
                    min: 0,
                    max: 12,
                    labels: {
                        step: 1,
                    }
                }, {
                    title: { text: 'Sequenza temporale' },
                    opposite: true,
                }],
                series: [{
                     name: 'Sequenza temporale',
                     type: 'histogram',
                     xAxis: 1,
                     yAxis: 1,
                     baseSeries: 's1',
                     zIndex: -1
                }, {
                    name: 'Articoli',
                    type: 'scatter',
                    data: data,
                    id: 's1',
                    marker: {
                        radius: 1.5
                    }
                }]
        })
})
})
</script>
<div id="prova" height="400px" width="800px"></div>
```

Comment: Could you add a picture of how that chart would look with your example data?

Comment: The original chart is this: [link](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/histogram). I want that the columns shows the sum of the values for each year, and the points mark each element according to year, month and day. In short, i would like a kind of timeline. Thanks

Comment: I don't quite understand how this chart should look like while there're months on the y axis. Is this what you want to achieve: http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/zdomyfvr/